# Click to upload an image "The server returned an invalid JSON response."

Tags: server, json

When I go into an article, and then click to upload an image I receive the error:

> The server returned an invalid JSON response.

I actually receive the error twice in a row if that helps.  Can anyone help to explain why this might happen?

I have debugging turned on.  Could that be the cause?

It doesn't show any images or folders, but navigating to the "media manager" does show these items.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it appears to be a bug in Joomla and should be raised on the Issue Tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only occurs when debug is turned on and it is **a JCE issue**.

I have contacted JCE separately.

Comment: So Joomla is effectively printing the expected json plus the debugging text which renders the whole enchilada as an invalid json string?  Were you able to use your browser's developer tools to see the exact content generated?

Comment: So if this is a bug to be fixed in the Joomla core, are we keeping this page alive?

Comment: This was a JCE error my bad

Comment: I can't delete it on my phone I'll do it from PC

Comment: I think although it is off topic, it might be something that someone else runs into so perhaps it should be left for Google's sake?  What are your thoughts?  It was JCE but someone else might think it was Joomla! and it helps preserve Joomlas reputation by answering the question

Comment: @Lodder your thoughts?